# How to display the WHOLE CONTENTS of a Google Doc on a Google Sites webpage?

Tags: google-docs, google-classic-sites, embed, iframe

I belong to a club which has a Google Sites website.  Various documents (Board minutes, schedules, newsletters, etc.) have been embedded on pages of this website.  The embedding is very unattractive.  You have to click again to see the whole contents.

Is there a way to insert the contents of the Google Doc directly on the page?  Without the frame thingie?

Comment: Consider showing an example what you mean through screenshots, or a link to a website that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To make the documents available through your Google Site so that they open in full-page view, insert in a list of *links* to those documents, like this:

1. Click **Insert > Text box**.
2. Click the **Numbered list** icon.
3. Click the **Insert link** icon.
4. Enter the name of a document in the **Text** box.
5. Paste the address of the document in the **Link** box.
6. Click **Apply**.
7. Repeat steps 3-6 with any additional documents.

To get the link to paste in step 5, open a document in another browser tab and choose **File > Publish to the web > Link**.

If the documents are not public and you want to authenticate users, use **File > Share > Copy link** instead of **File > Publish to the web > Link**.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I don't want the user to have to click to get to the document.  I want the contents of the Google Doc to be displayed as content on the page.  Does that make it clearer?  That's how it works when you embed a Google Calendar.  You can see the whole month.  I want to see the whole doc.  I don't want there to be a frame within the page.  There should only be one scrollbar -- the usual one, that comes with the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try tomorrow.  I feel encouraged and I appreciate your help.

Comment: I finally had time to test it.  First, I think that part about the list was unnecessary, and confusing for my collaborator.  Anyway, I'm glad there's no frame, but I still am not able to get the content to appear directly on the web page.  I still have to click to get to the content.

Comment: Consider showing an example what you mean through a series screenshots that show how you currently navigate from the website's front page to the page that contains the documents, or a link to a website that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I do find this somewhat of an improvement.  Thank you.